# Widget added as the first by requestPinAppWidget and removed manually is not call onDisabled method for AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android

If you add a widget by `requestPinAppWidget` then `onEnabled` is call, but if you remove it from the Home screen `onDisabled` is not call (of course it is the last removed widget). What is wrong or it is a bug?

Answer (score 1):

`onDisabled` is only called when the last AppWidget instance for this provider is deleted.

If you want to get a callback on any AppWidget being deleted, you must override `onDeleted`.

[For more info see the official documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider)